# Supremum of lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Consider a lower semicontinuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ and a set-valued mapping $X : \mathbb{R}^m \rightrightarrows \mathbb{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{X}$ is compact.

Define the function 
$$ \varphi(x) := \sup_{ y \in X(x) } f(y). $$

I am wondering if $\varphi$ is lower semicontinuous.

(I found that "the supremum of a family of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous".)

I started with the definition: $\varphi$ lsc if whenever $x_n \rightarrow x$, we have $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \varphi(x_n) \geq \varphi(x) $, i.e., $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{ y \in X(x_n) } f(y) \geq \sup_{ y \in X(x) } f(y) $. Then we should exploit the compactness of $X$.

Comment: If the set $X(x)$ doesn't depend in a nice way on $x$, you have no hope of proving semicontinuity. How does $X(x)$ depend on $x$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What if $X$ is outer semicontinuous?

Comment: What does outer semicontinuous mean?

Comment: A set-valued mapping $S: \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^m $ is outer semicontinuous at $\bar x$ if 
$$ \limsup_{x \rightarrow \bar x} S(x) \subset S(\bar x) $$

or equivalently $\limsup_{x \rightarrow \bar x} S(x) = S(\bar x)$.

Comment: Aha. That may do it. I have other things to do before I can think about whether that indeed does it, though.